Disabling Cloudflare's Wrangler production deployment for specific users
We are using Cloudflare's serverless workers and also their very convenient Wrangler tool for deployments (staging and production). Staging and production workers are just two separate workers, not much important difference between them, besides environments and some WAF rules.
Currently any developer can deploy to production worker via Wrangler, since Cloudflare doesn't have any permissions/policies for that, as far as we know.
We would like to have production deployments only through the CI/CD, so devs can't just deploy to production from the local machine. Or at least to have possibility of limiting the users to do so.
Is there any way to do this in Cloudflare? E.g. are there any permissions/policies, which we aren't aware, and which offer fine grained permissions to specific users? Or does maybe Wrangler itself offer something in that manner? Also we are open for any other workarounds.
Thanks

At present, I think the best way to do this is to avoid giving developers access to the production Cloudflare account at all. There are two basic ways you could approach this:

Don't give developers any access to Cloudflare. They can still test their changes locally with wrangler dev. They won't be able to use wrangler dev --remote, but these days it's becoming less important as the fidelity of the local dev simulation has improved a lot.
Create a separate staging account and give developers access to that. They can freely deploy all they want to staging and even run wrangler dev --remote using it, but won't have access to production. You will probably want to define separate Wrangler Environments for staging and production since they will need to bind to different resources (e.g. different KV namespaces).

With that said, we (Cloudflare) recognize these solutions are not always ideal and are working on making this better.

Hi! Thanks for the reply.
Since we already have devs using CF, we are not planning on removing that.
Regarding the separate account, this could be a good solution. Since we won't remove devs from CF, does CF offer more granular permissions in the workers context, or is there a single one which just enables/disables users to do any edits in the worker context?
